dart named parameters as object
I'm new to dart. I'm trying to factorize some code, and it involves pre-building a few values which are then passed into named parameters (external library).
I'd like to know if i can do the following:
dynamic prepareArgs() {
  return {
    "bar": 1,
  }
}

void myFunc(String foo, { num: bar }); // ← the said external library

void main() {
  myFunc("hello", ...prepareArgs());
}

i know that, type-wise, it doesn't check out. what i'm looking for is a solution to make this happen. can i avoid passing a dozen named parameters at every myFunc call?

You could have the function prepareArgs return a record with named fields.

@DanR could you provide an example in an answer? if that works i'd love to accept this as an answer.

That can be done if you use a wrapping function (there's no overloading in dart). With Function.apply you can call a function and pass arguments to the function without directly specifying them.
Map<String, dynamic> prepareArgs() {
  return {
    "bar": 1,
    "ber": [2, 3]
  };
}

bool myFunc(String foo, {int? bar, List<int>? ber}) {
  print('myFunc(foo: "$foo", bar: $bar, ber: $ber)');
  return true;
}

bool myMetaFunc(String foo, Map<String, dynamic> kargs) {
  return Function.apply(
    myFunc,
    [foo],
    kargs.map((k, v) => MapEntry(Symbol(k), v)),
  );
}

void main() {
  final ok = myMetaFunc('hello', prepareArgs());
}


in the end this mean this means no, but i understand. the goal was to avoid anything hand written but i understand dart cannot do it.
